# Why MySQL FROM_UNIXTIME() returns different result in different mysql server version?

Tags: mysql

My product has a table as below,paytime is varchar, addtime is int:

> desc test1;

```
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| paytime | varchar(30)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| addtime | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

server A>select version();

```
+-----------------+
| version()       |
+-----------------+
| 5.6.36-82.0-log |
+-----------------+
```

server B>select version();

```
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.5.33-log |
+------------+
```

server A>select from_unixtime(paytime),from_unixtime(addtime) from test1;

```
+----------------------------+------------------------+
| from_unixtime(paytime)     | from_unixtime(addtime) |
+----------------------------+------------------------+
| 2018-01-18 01:56:12.000000 | 2018-01-18 01:56:12    |
+----------------------------+------------------------+
```

server B>select from_unixtime(paytime),from_unixtime(addtime) from test1;

```
+------------------------+------------------------+
| from_unixtime(paytime) | from_unixtime(addtime) |
+------------------------+------------------------+
| 2018-01-18 01:56:12    | 2018-01-18 01:56:12    |
+------------------------+------------------------+
```

as you can see,when i use from_unixtime, mysql 5.5 returns '2018-01-18 01:56:12', mysql 5.6 returns '2018-01-18 01:56:12' when the arguement is string type. any one knows the reason?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bug reported](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72761) related to this behavior.

To fix your issue until the bug is resolved, one workaround is to specify the `datetime` format explicitly in `from_unixtime`

```
SELECT from_unixtime('1516240572', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');

Output:- 2018-01-18 01:56:12
```

[Reference Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)